# Optimal method to numerically integrate a spectral distribution data

Tags: numerical-methods, physics

I am trying to numerically integrate a spectral distribution data. A spectral distribution function gives the Luminosity per Wavelength of an object (like a galaxy) as a function of the Wavelength. In more mathematical terms,

$$ dL(\lambda) = \rho(\lambda) d\lambda$$

where $L$ = Luminosity in ($\lambda+d\lambda$, $\lambda$); $\rho$ = spectral distribution function; $\lambda$ = Wavelength.

The problem is I am not presented with the spectral distribution function per se. What I am given is the value of this function at discrete wavelengths. For example, my data would look like:

```
==================================
|Wavelength|Spectral Distribution|
|   ...    |         ...         |
|   248    |         500         |
|   300    |         510         |
|   305    |         512         |
|   306    |         518         |
|   ...    |         ...         | 
==================================
```

Please do observe that the wavelength's are not varying in a regular fashion. Up until now I've been just using the following primitive formula to find the total luminosity.

$$\Delta L=\frac{(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)}{2}[\rho_2+\rho_1]$$
$$L = \sum \Delta \lambda$$

Is there any other method that I use which gives an improvement over this method I am using?

---

EDIT: Here is a plot of $\log_{10}(\rho)$ vs $\lambda$:

[image]

Comment: Could you show a plot of your $\rho(\lambda)$ values? Do you have any plausible functional form for what your $\rho$ looks like (a la Planck, for instance)?

Comment: @J. M. I've added a plot of $\log_{10}(\rho)$ vs $\lambda$. Unfortunately I don't know what the functional form of $\rho$ is.

Comment: Quite noisy, apparently... do you think the usual assumption of only $\rho$ is error-contaminated applies, or do we also have to account for errors in $\lambda$? If the machine determines at which $\lambda$ to sample, then I guess we can assume that the $\lambda$ are error-free...

Comment: @J. M. Actually this is not a real experimental data. This data is from a numerical simulation of a cluster of stars (which in turn uses real data with errors) As you said, the $\lambda$'s can be considered error-free.

Comment: Least-squares may or may not be the best way to determine a $\rho(\lambda)$ that you can subsequently integrate. Does the physics/theory really not suggest any plausible form for $\rho$? I was about to suggest splines until I saw your plot...

Comment: By least-squares you mean to fit the curve? Actually, there is not much of a theory behind this. This is the result of simulating the evolution of a collection of stars in a galaxy. This is not something like a Planck distribution for a black body. So I don't think fitting the curve would be advantageous at  all.

Comment: With noisy data, you really can't do better than Trapezoid or Midpoint rule for numerical integration.

Comment: @Robert Thanks! Could you elaborate a bit more, and if possible make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider trying to approximate $J = \int_a^b f(x)\, dx$ given noisy values of a smooth function $f$ at $N+1$ equally spaced points $x_i = a + i (b-a)/N$, $i=0 \ldots N$.  Thus what you are given is $y_i = f(x_i) + \epsilon_i$ where $\epsilon_i$ are independent  random variables with mean 0 and standard deviation $\sigma$.  A typical quadrature rule would be of the form $A = \sum_i w_i y_i$ where 
$\sum_i w_i = b-a$.  The error $J - A$ consists of two parts, the truncation error
$T = J - \sum_i w_i f(x_i)$ and the random error $R = \sum_i w_i \epsilon_i$.  For the 
Trapezoid Rule (all $w_i = (b-a)/N$) the truncation error is $O(1/N^2)$, and other quadrature rules can make the truncation error go to 0 much faster as $N \to \infty$.
On the other hand, the random error has standard deviation $\sigma \sqrt{\sum_i w_i^2}$.
which is at least $\sigma (b-a)/\sqrt{N}$ (the minimum being attained for the Trapezoid Rule).
This is because 
$$ \sum_i w_i^2 = (b-a)^2/N + \sum_i (w_i - (b-a)/N)^2 $$
Thus for large $N$ the random error is much larger than the truncation error, and the Trapezoid Rule (which minimizes the standard deviation of the random error) will work better than other rules that have less truncation error but greater random error.